# Angular 7 material cards looks like pinterest?

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, angular-material, pinterest

Is there a way to make the angular material cards looks like pinterest layout?

this is my code:

```
<div fxFlex fxLayout="column" fxLayoutGap="10px" style="height: 100vh">
  <div fxLayout="row wrap">
    <!-- loop over the cardList and show the cards -->
    <div
      *ngFor="let card of cardList"
      fxFlex="25"
      fxFlex.md="33"
      fxFlex.sm="50"
      fxFlex.xs="100"
      fxLayout="column"
      style="padding: 5px;"
    >
      <!-- cards here -->
      <mat-card class="mat-elevation-z1">
        <img mat-card-image [src]="card.imgSrc" />
        <mat-card-title> {{ card.title }} </mat-card-title>
        <mat-card-content> {{ card.description }} </mat-card-content>
        <mat-card-footer>
          <button fxFlex mat-flat-button color="primary">
            Do Something Button
          </button>
        </mat-card-footer>
      </mat-card>
    </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

[image: example]

I would like to avoid that blank space and fill it with part of the others cards, just like pinterest does

Or something familiar as bootstrap does , for example:

[image: bootstrap example]

Is it even possible in angular material cards? I've search in the web and no luck yet, please if someone know a way, help me... thanks!

Comment: Why have you tagged this bootstrap? Have you looked to see how Pinterest gets that effect on their site? (A Material panel is only a glorified div, after all; you can position it how you'd like.)

Comment: You can use CSS

Comment: You can use a flexbox

Answer (score 0):

You can use boostrap to place your cards inside an element with class "col-3" and replicate this element three more times to create four columns each with as many cards as you want.

Don`t forget to create your four columns inside of a "row" class element.